# How to solve java.net.UnknownHostException: mosquitto in docker container?

Tags: java, docker, mqtt

I am running a Java application which successfully connects to a MQTT broker locally like this:

`ws://localhost:9001` and then has to do the same in a docker container for `ws://mosquitto:9001`. This used to work fine but I found now that I get this issue:

```
Failed to connect to the MQTT broker with address ws://mosquitto:9001 MqttException (0) - java.net.UnknownHostException: mosquitto
```

I receive no other error so I wonder what could be the cause of this since it used to work fine before.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @Kai-ShengYang Which code do you want to see? The mqtt connection?

Comment: We need to know a lot more about your docker configuration, e.g. are you using docker-compose, if so we need to see the docker-compose file

Answer (score 1):

you may go to https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2074
where scott has mentioned

This broke for me when Watchtower upgraded this to 2.0.7 also. Adding the following to the config file and a restart fixed things for me:

listener 1883

Comment: I have this line in my mqtt config file.